# Pixel stack for opacity (passing an object vs passing a string and parsing)

Tags: arrays, parsing, stack, queue, unity-game-engine

I've got a paint program I've been working on, and I've started to tackle opacity. I'm at a point now where I compare the background color to the brush color, average the two based on their alphas, and then set a new pixel. I just need to cache a portion of what I'm drawing off to the side so that it doesn't continuously sample what is continuously changing while the mouse is down. I figured I would fix this by throwing 50 pixels into a stack or queue that starts changing pixels on screen once it's full and completely empties all it's contents onto the screen on mouse up. What I'd like to know is what would be more efficient, two stacks (one of coordinates and one of colors) or one stack of strings that I parse into coordinates and colors.
TLDR: What's more efficient, two stacks of different data types, or one string stack that I parse into two data types.

Comment: I guess I'll just try one and post how it performs if anyone eventually has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems longer and more confusing than it needs to be, but I think what you're asking is:

> I'm designing a paint program. If the user is painting 50%-opaque black pixels on a white background, I want them to show up as gray. My problem is that if the user draws a curve that crosses itself, or just leaves the mouse cursor in the same place for a while, the repeated pixels become darker and darker: 50% black, then 75%, then 87.5%... I don't want this. As long as the mouse button is down, no pixel should be "painted" twice, no matter how many times the curve crosses itself.

This question answers itself. The only way to keep pixels from being painted twice is to keep track of which pixels have been painted since the last time the mouse button was up. Replace

```
image[mouse.x][mouse.y] = alpha_average(image[mouse.x][mouse.y], current_color, current_alpha);
```

with

```
if (not already_painted[mouse.x][mouse.y]) {
    image[mouse.x][mouse.y] = alpha_average(image[mouse.x][mouse.y], current_color, current_alpha);
    already_painted[mouse.x][mouse.y] = true;
}

handle(mouse_up) {
    already_painted[*][*] = false;
}
```

Problem solved, right?

But to answer another implied question: If you're trying to choose between [a bunch of parallel arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array) and [a bunch of data stuffed into strings](http://google.com/search?q=everything+is+a+string), you're probably doing it wrong. All Unity3D languages (Python, C#, Javascript) support struct/class/dict types *and* tuples, either of which would be a better idea than parallel arrays or everything-is-a-string-ism.